# Female/feminine version of "Hooligan"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there such a word?

To be used when speaking of the "tough girl" or the tomboy your parents don't want you to be involved with. The troublemaker in girl form.

Best I've come up with so far is Ruffian but I'm wondering if there's anything else that fits.

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider "ringleaders" .  I'm not sure any of these are really sexed but the behaviors associated with the words lend themselves to association with (stereotypical?) traits one sex or another is prone to demonstrate.  Female bullies are often disparaged as being "collusive" and "manipulative" more than violent or vandalous.

Comment: I think ["bad girl"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bad_girl) comes fairly close, but for some it's a badge of honour. On the other hand, *troublemaker* is used for both sexes, and a sufficiently derogatory term. I'd use that one.

Comment: Might ["ladette]"(http://www.dictionary.com/browse/ladette) work? > *(informal) a young woman whose social behaviour is similar to that of male adolescents or young men*

Comment: Why not just stick with *hooligan?*  A preponderance of [dictionary definitions](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hooligan) seem to admit of a hooligan's being female, and *Collins Spanish Dictionary* even explicitly offers "gamberro/a *m/f"* as the Spanish equivalent. The notion that separate male and female terms are required for a single sort of deviancy would seem to derive from an assumption that it deviates in markedly different directions from male and female gender norms and expectations--and that assumption seems both sexist and dated.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that *ruffian* has anything to do with gender, or that *hooligan* needs to?

Comment: I agree that *hooligan* is gender-neutral, but if you want to stress that you have a female specimen of the species you could try *hooligal*.

Comment: I wasn't meaning to make it overtly sexist. Honestly just whenever I think of the term hooligan I think of a rowdy bunch of guys and an old man shouting at them to get off their lawn. As far as ruffian goes, I felt it was slightly more feminine in nature but still "brutal" in the aspect of attitude. I am loving all of these suggestions! I like the idea of Hooligal as well, might be fun to put a twist on some of the other suggestions and synonyms as well!

Comment: A bad influence.  A piece of work.  A nasty girl.  An instigator.

Answer (score 3):

Just to be plain, and setting aside modern uses for the moment, the original 'hooligans' were boys:

> [image: hooligan 1894]
>
> [*London Daily News*, 24 April 1894](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000051/18940424/015/0004) (paywalled).

This and numerous other similar references in the intervening years antedate *OED*'s earliest, July 1898, attestation of the term in the sense of "A young street rough, a member of a street gang." However, by August of 1898, the 'hooligan girl' appears on the scene, with a vengeance:

> [image: hooligan 1898-3]
>
> [*Yorkshire Evening Press*, 26 August 1898](http://www.britishnewspaperarchive.co.uk/viewer/bl/0000632/18980826/089/0004) (paywalled).

As remarked in the clipping, no one sex has a monopoly on hooliganism. That circumstance prevails to this day.